# Show data by month, not day?

Tags: carto, torque

I have time data about transactions by month. I'd like a Torque visualisation with a month-by-month slider. The raw data looks like this:

```
month,lat,lng,transactions
January 2014,52.2,0.0,7
January 2014,52.7,0.0,10
February 2014,52.2,0.0,10
February 2014,52.7,0.0,20
```

I'm not sure how to do this. CartoDB's "date" columns want dates which specify a day (not unreasonably), so it becomes more like this:

```
01/01/2014,52.7,0.0,20
01/02/2014,52.7,0.0,20
```

Then when I use the Torque visualisation, I get a brief flash on these days, but the map is mostly black. I guess I could get around this by adding a row for every single day, but that would make my data file unmanageably large (it's already over 100MB).

The other way I could get around this is to specify the steps in the slider as always being the first of the month. However, this doesn't seem to be possible right now.

How can I show data by month?

Answer (score 1):

If you have X months in your dataset, you can try to add X+1 steps in your CartoCSS specific code for the Torque properties.

Take into account that the steps don't show the data at the specific date that appears in the timeslider but they aggregate the data within the interval `[ step_{n} and step_{n+1} )`.